# "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, user-input, explicit, sharpdevelop, formatexception

"System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

This keeps stopping my program and telling me that I have not converted the user input to an integer (because user input is initially a string type).

Here's the code for my C# project:

```
using System;
namespace Project1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("PREPARING GAME: HEADS AND TAILS");
            Console.WriteLine("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE");
            Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("PICK A NUMBER:");
            Console.WriteLine("1: HEADS");
            Console.WriteLine("2: TAILS");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            int playerNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //Where the trouble happens
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why it keeps reporting the same error if I thought I fixed it already with the `Convert.ToInt32()` method. I tried converting it to int16 instead of int32 since the whole numbers are small but it still throws the same exception error. I don't think I would need a double either because I really am only asking for a small whole number.

Comment: what are you typing in?

Comment: @DanielA.White C# You can also check tags

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32("C#")` would indeed throw that error - try typing in an integer :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It doesn't let me type anything in: like I said, it stops the program right there.

Comment: Change the first `Read()` call to `ReadLine()` - you're probably hitting some other key and then hitting Enter, thus resulting in `Console.ReadLine()` returning an empty string

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32("5")` -- ok. `Convert.ToInt32("x")` -- System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Use `ReadLine` or `ReadKey` instead of `Console.Read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.Read()` reads one char off the input stream, a windows carriage-return is two characters `\r\n` so you are leaving `\n` in the buffer.

When you reach your `Console.ReadLine()` it's reading the rest of the input buffer (`\n`) which is passed as a parameter to `Convert.ToInt32("\n")` and an exception is thrown.

Change the first `Read()` call to `ReadLine()` to read the full carriage-return from the buffer, then the buffer will be empty when you reach the next `ReadLine()`.